# Typed.js isn't loading up in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, typed.js

I've made a function for my index.cshtml and written that in index.js, this file uses the Typed.js library, but it doesn't find it. I included both typed.js and typed.min.js. Should I link the scripts instead of the _layout file in the index.cshtml?

This is my _layout.cshtml:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/typed.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   
    

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
   
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            
            <img src="~/Content/images/atoslogo.png" class="img-responsive" style="height: 100px" />
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    
</body>

</html>
```

The function itself (index.js) :

```js
function typerJS() {
    if (counter == 0) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(".element0").typed({
                strings: ["Wachten op de eerste sensordata... (0/3)"],
                typeSpeed: 30, // typing speed
                backDelay: 750, // pause before backspacing
                loop: false, // loop on or off (true or false)
                loopCount: false, // number of loops, false = infinite
                callback: function () { } // call function after typing is done
            });
        }, 0);
    }
    if (counter == 1) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(".element1").css("display", "inherit");
            $(".element1").typed({
                strings: ["Wachten op de eerste sensordata...(1/3)"],
                typeSpeed: 30, // typing speed
                backDelay: 750, // pause before backspacing
                loop: false, // loop on or off (true or false)
                loopCount: false, // number of loops, false = infinite
                callback: function () { } // call function after typing is done
            });
        }, 2000);
    }

    if (counter == 2) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(".element2").css("display", "inherit");
            $(".element2").typed({
                strings: ["Wachten op de eerste sensordata... (2/3)"],
                typeSpeed: 30, // typing speed
                backDelay: 750, // pause before backspacing
                loop: false, // loop on or off (true or false)
                loopCount: false, // number of loops, false = infinite
                callback: function () { } // call function after typing is done
            });
        }, 4000);
    }

    if (counter == 3) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(".element3").css("display", "inherit");
            $(".element3").typed({
                strings: ["Wachten op de eerste sensordata...(3/3)"],
                typeSpeed: 30, // typing speed
                backDelay: 750, // pause before backspacing
                loop: false, // loop on or off (true or false)
                loopCount: false, // number of loops, false = infinite
                callback: function () { } // call function after typing is done
            });
        }, 6000);
    }

    if (counter == 3) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(".element4").css("display", "inherit");
            $(".element4").typed({
                strings: ["U wordt zo spoedig mogelijk doorgestuurd.."],
                typeSpeed: 30, // typing speed
                backDelay: 750, // pause before backspacing
                loop: false, // loop on or off (true or false)
                loopCount: false, // number of loops, false = infinite
                callback: function () { } // call function after typing is done
            });
        }, 6000);
    }
}
```

The error I get:
[image]

Anybody knows what i'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: It seems like `jQuery` didn't finished loading. Try to execute your function in the `$.ready` callback.

Comment: JQuery did load up. Other js functions did work

Comment: First of all: `JavaScript` != `jQuery`. And please post the content of your `index.js` where the error appears

Comment: I know. Index.js is the function edited it. The error appears on .typed

Comment: yeah totally right as you're calling a non-existent `jQuery` function..... Please look at my answer!

Answer (score 0):

Now I've looked up `Typed.js` and just looked at the documentation. This took me less then a minute.

You're problem is, that you want to use `Typed.js` and you used `jQuery`.

A sample setup of `Typed.js` looks like this:

```
var typed = new Typed('.element', {
    strings: [
        "First sentence.",
        "Second sentence."
    ],
    typeSpeed: 30
});
```

So you just have to simply look at the manual and then use it correctly.

For you this means:

Just use the code you already have and then use `new Typed("x", ...)` instead of `$("x").typed(...)`.

```
new Typed("element0", {
    strings: ["Wachten op de eerste sensordata... (0/3)"], 
    typeSpeed: 30, // typing speed
    backDelay: 750, // pause before backspacing
    loop: false, // loop on or off (true or false)
    loopCount: false, // number of loops, false = infinite
    callback: function () { } // call function after typing is done
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use this cdn's

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/typed.js/1.1.4/typed.min.js"></script>
```

and use an external script of:

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#hero").typed({
                strings: [val.quote],
                typeSpeed: 110, // typing speed
                backDelay: 500, // pause before backspacing
                loop: trueenter code here
            });
});
```